# Как правильно высвободить ресурс в golang?

Tags: golang

Использую golang 1.5.
Использую библиотеку [gopkg.in/rana/ora.v3](http://gopkg.in/rana/ora.v3) для подключения к Oracle.

В пример [Working With The Oracle Package Directly](https://github.com/rana/ora#working-with-the-oracle-package-directly) есть реализация использования ресурса Oracle environment:

```
env, err := ora.OpenEnv(nil)
defer env.Close()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Мы видим, что в `defer` закрытие ресурса идёт напрямую через ссылку env.

Но что будет если произойдёт сбой. В реализации [OpenEnv](https://github.com/rana/ora/blob/master/ora.go) мы видим, что при ошибке для env возвращается значение nil. С эмитируем данную ситуацию:

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/rana/ora.v3"
    "errors"
)

func main() {   
    defer fmt.Println("Hello")

    // env, err := ora.OpenEnv(nil)

    var env *ora.Env = nil
    var err error = errors.New("Test error")
    defer env.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Получаем следующее сообщение об ошибки:

> Hello
>   panic: Test error
>     panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>   [signal 0xc0000005 code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x48753a]
>
> goroutine 1 [running]:
>   gopkg.in/rana/ora%2ev3.(*Env).Close(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)

И хоть мы видим, что возникшая ошибка не прерывает выполнение остальных `defer` методов, но ошибка всё таки фиксируется.

Корректно ли оставлять так?
Или всё же стоит гарантировать, что при `evn == nil` `defer env.Close()` никогда не вызовется?
Или в теле метода, переданного в `defer`, следует проверять `env` на `nil`?

```
defer func () { if env != nil { env.Close() }}()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defer` обычно ставится *после* проверки на ошибку, как раз из-за того, что большинство функций, возвращающих указатель и `error`, в случае ошибки возвращают `nil`. Например:

```
f, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
if err != nil {
        panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()
```

Пример в той библиотеке с этой точки зрения действительно странные. ЕМНИП, все примеры в стандартной библиотеке вызывают `defer` после проверки. Например, в [`database/sql`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#example_DB_Query).

Comment: А вам не кажется, что использование `log.Fatal(err)` является тоже не корректным. Ведь реализация `log.Fatal` содержит `os.Exit(1)`, т.е. выполнение программы буде прервано и "Hello" не будет выведено, т.е. не будут корректно закрыты другие ресурсы.

Comment: Это всего-лишь пример. Заменил на `panic`.

Comment: Но, если данный шаблон рассматривать как стандарт, то что гарантирует, что `f == nil`? А если он не `nil`, то для надёжности всё таки стоит дернуть `Close`? Т.е. я хочу сказать что данный шаблон не универсален, в нём есть условие.

Comment: Гарантий нет. Даже если будет ситуация, при которой `f != nil`, нет гарантий, что `f.Close()` что-нибудь не поломает, не запаникует или не вернёт другую ошибку. Смотрите по ситуации, по конкретным ресурсам, по документации модуля и по требованиям к устойчивости.

Comment: Получается, что использования, например в c#, Exception и try-catch-finally/using даёт большую определённость в действиях, чем обработка ошибок в golang.

Comment: @MaLS, ну, в C# тоже вам никто не гарантирует, что в finally ссылка на ресурс не null

Comment: @hardsky Да. Но в практике ссылку всегда проверяют на `null`. И в `using` она тоже проверяется.

Comment: @MaLS, всегда можно вставить `recover`, если документация не позволяет понять, что вернёт функция. А `try/catch/finally` вообще не выход - проверка `if ptr == nil {}` в разы быстрее. Идеальный вариант - это сообщить автору библиотеки, что её следует поправить (ещё лучше сделать пул-реквест) и больше не париться об этом.